# Genymotion/React Native Perf Monitor Stutter

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, genymotion

I'm in the process of releasing my first React Native app and I'm looking at the Perf Monitor and wondering what "XX stutters" are. I've managed to investigate what "dropped so far" is and to my understanding that is caused when my app drops below the ideal 60fps mark and it's not something I should worry about too much.

To summarise then, my questions are:

1. What are stutters/what is the cause?
2. Should I be concerned with them if so how to deal with them?
3. Is my assumption of "dropped so far" correct?

Many thanks in advance.